# contains elements hashmap in arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

i have `hashmap<integer,arraylist<integer>> H`  and `arraylist<integer> L`
 i want test if first element in arraylist is similar at first value in hashmap
this what i want

```
 for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
        Integer key1 = e.getKey();

        List<Integer> valeur = e.getValue();
        int count = 0;
        int k = 0;
        //Integer temp : listOperateur;

        if (valeur.contains(listOperateur)) {
            count++;


        }

        sim.put(key1, count);
        k++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code can help you

```
    Iterator i1 = listOperateur.iterator();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
       //if (e.getValue() != null) {
            count = 0;
            //you can move this part to another method to avoid deep nested code
            for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {
                // for (Integer listValue : listOperateur) {
                if (mapValue.equals(listOperateur.get(k))) {
                    count++;
                    //  }
                }
            }
            sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
            k++;
      //  }
    }
```